# Mayor velocidad navegacion segues ios swift

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

Estoy haciendo una pp que contiene varias pantallas y tengo que ir navegando entre ellas. El problema es que al navegar a algunas pantallas tarda demasiado en aparecer la otra. Como puedo añadir mas velocidad en las transiciones???

Mi código:

```
func cancelar() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("volver", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Simplemente no puedes, tienes que saber qué diferencia una de las otras. ¿En las pantallas "lentas" cargas datos del servidor o similar?

Comment: Por que no utilizar un `UIPageViewController`? dentro de este puedes incluir todos los `UIViewControllers` o pantallas como le llamas y puedes incluso aprovechar los gestos `SwipeLeft` y `SwipeRight` para el cambio entre views o hacerlo manualmente implementando los respectivos protocolos `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` y `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`. Eso sería rápido, Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El segue tiene la misma velocidad en todos los sitios.
Tu problema reside en que en algunos controladores estas cargando datos a la hora de cargar la pantalla , por lo tanto hasta que no cargue los datos no carga bien la pantalla. 
Recuerda que lo aconsejable para hacer llamadas a webservices o base de datos u otro tipo de información es aconsejable hacerlo siempre en **viewWillAppear** o **viewDidAppear**